# encountered x509 error when running docker ps after running eval $(minikube docker-env)

Tags: docker, kubernetes, x509, minikube

I encountered this error below after running

```
eval $(minikube docker-env)
docker ps

error during connect: Get 
https://192.168.99.181:2376/v1.40/containers/json: x509: certificate signed 
by unknown authority
```

Here is some details when I ran

```
minikube docker-env

export DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY="1"  
export DOCKER_HOST="tcp://192.168.99.181:2376"  
export DOCKER_CERT_PATH="/Users/myuser.name/.minikube/certs"
```

I am using MACOS.

Comment: Appreciate your help...

Comment: Which minikube Version are you using? 
Is the problem solved when deleting and recreating the minikube vm?

Comment: here is my minikube version: v1.4.0 also the docker version 19.03.2; already tried deleting and recreating the minikube vm but still the same error shows up.

Comment: Do you have a proxy server configured?

Comment: We are currently using forticlient VPN. Is that going to be an issue?

Comment: VPN should not be a problem, a proxy server could lead to accessing a different service than you expect.

Comment: I checked proxies on network preferences and I don't seem to see anything checked on the options.

Comment: Not sure what happened but its now working and I don't see the x509 error anymore.. I tried deleting minikube and then ran skaffold which build the images but not able to deploy since minikube is not up. I then started minikube and the reran skaffold and everything went fine now for some reason.